# How to pass dependency to AsyncNotifier with the new Riverpod syntax?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod, riverpod-annotation

I'm currently using the new Riverpod syntax but I'm having an error and haven't been able to find a solution. I need to pass a dependency but it gives me this error **The class TaskHomeInit must have a default constructor**. Does anyone know another way to pass the HomeRepository dependency to it. When I don't place the constructor the error is that it needs to be initialized.

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class TaskHomeInit extends _$TaskHomeInit {
  final HomeRepository homeRepository;
  // Constructor
  TaskHomeInit({required this.homeRepository}); // here is error
  @override
  Future<TasksHomeState> build() async {
    final List<TaskHome> taskHome = await homeRepository.getTaskHome();
    return TasksHomeState(isLoading: false, tasksHome: taskHome);
  }
}
```

When I don't create the constructor, I get this error: `The final variable 'homeRepository' must be initialized. Try initializing the variable.`

*HomeRepository abstract class*

```
abstract class HomeRepository {
  Future<List<TaskHome>> getTaskHome();
}
```

*Implementation HomeRepository*

```
class HomeRepositoryImpl extends HomeRepository {
  final HomeDatasource datasource;
  HomeRepositoryImpl(this.datasource);
  @override
  Future<List<TaskHome>> getTaskHome() async {
    final test =  await datasource.getTaskHome();
    return test;
  }
}
```

Comment: Typically, a Notifier property is marked "late" and then initialized in build from a family or ref.watch.  They should not be passed in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In riverpod world, dependency injection is usually done with the `Ref` object.
Instead of injecting the dependency via constructor, create a provider.

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
HomeRepository homeRepo(HomeRepoRef ref) => HomeRepositoryImpl(ref.watch(homeDatasourceProvider);

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
HomeDatasource homeDatasource(HomeDatasourceRef ref) => HomeDatasourceImpl();
```

Inside the `Notifier/AsyncNotifier`'s build method, use `ref.watch` to access the dependency. It is safe and recommended to use `ref.watch` inside the build method.

```dart
@override
Future<TasksHomeState> build() async {
  final repo = ref.watch(homeRepoProvider);
  final taskHome = await repo.getTaskHome();
  return ...
}
```

Comment: Hello @Charles, thanks for your answer. I tried to create a provider equal to the one you gave me in the response and it gives me this error en el nuevo provider `Abstract classes can't be instantiated.
Try creating an instance of a concrete subtype.`, I updated the question and attached the class code and its implementation
```

Comment: It's similar to what you would normally do with dependency injection via constructor. You inject the concrete one.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked correctly for me now!!!